# Finding the kinetic energy without exactly knowing the motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, point-particles

let $P$  be a point particle of mass $m$ simultaneously subjected to  elastic force $ \overrightarrow{F_1}= -k \overrightarrow{e_r}$ and the Newtonian $ \overrightarrow{F_2}= -\frac{\gamma}{r^2}$  with $ k,\gamma >0$ constants and $r = |P-O|$ with $O$ centre of the motion and $ \overrightarrow{e_r} = \overrightarrow{ \frac{(P-O)}{r}}  $ radial versor

Find the Effective potential energy $V_{eff}(r)$ of the motion knowing that$ r(0) = r_0 >0 , \dot{\phi}(0) = \dot{\phi}_0 \neq 0$ with $\phi$ the angle that the ray vector $(P − O)$ forms with a predetermined direction.

I know the following's, to find the $V_{eff}(r)$ I need to find the lagrangian $\mathscr{L}= T + V$ with $V$ potential energy and $T$ kinetic energy

we also know that $  - \nabla V = \overrightarrow { F} = \overrightarrow{ F}_1 +$ $\overrightarrow{F}_2 \implies -V = \int F dr \implies V = \frac{k}{2} r^2 - \gamma$ $\frac{1}{r}$

while the kinetic energy is $  T = \frac{1}{2}m ||\dot{x}(t) || ^2$, but with the following information, how can I find the motion in order to find the kinetic energy? I'm stuck in here and after I have found the kinetic energy I would like to know how to find the $ V_{eff}$ from the solutions (I only have the intermediate results ) I can find that the motion is simply written using the polar parametrization$\begin{bmatrix}
           x \\
           y
         \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
           rsin\phi \\
           rcos\phi
         \end{bmatrix}$ ,( I haven't found them, I simply guessed them and I'd like to know how to actually figure them out) but how do I come with such kind of conclusion based on the data?

Comment: You already have $x$ and $y$ in terms of $r$ and $\phi$; what stops you from just enacting the time derivative and the squaring and summing?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent sorry but where do i have x and y?

Comment: You yourself wrote that $$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end  {bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}r\sin\phi\\r\cos\phi\end  {bmatrix}$$ (and if the question did not tell you this, then you should swap $\sin$ and $\cos$ around).

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent i said that it is the motion, i figured out looking at the solution, the problem doesn't give it to me i supposed to find it out that's why i made the question on the first place

Comment: Polar coördinates is a standard transformation that you do not need to copy from the solution. You should be able to know it before you started trying to solve the problem, and reliably use it to get the answer. That is what I am trying to tell you.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent i know what are polar coordinates, i'm just saying how a'm i supposed to know that the motion has that set of coordinates? how do i actually figure it out

Comment: I am saying that you do not need to know the actual motion to know that you can plug in the polar coördinates and work out the KE terms in the Lagrangian. And I just told you how to do that.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent so my question is why i can just plug polar coordinates without knowing the motion?

Comment: Because when you are working with Lagrangian mechanics prior to solving the E-L equations, you actually do not know the motion. You are only trying to express the KE terms in the appropriate coördinates.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent i'm not an english native speaker can you tell me what E L KE stand for so i can go and translate it? and even more, if i have for example 3 curvilinear coordinates how am i supposed to know then if i need to use cylindric or spherical?

Comment: When talking about Lagrangian mechanics, E-L equations can only mean Euler-Lagrange equations. KE is kinetic energy. It does not matter how many dimensions you have, coördinates are only coördinates if you can express all positions within the domain of applicability, and that means you can express all velocities.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent so any set of coordinates is fine?

Comment: Yes, as long as they are coördinates at all.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent so what's the point knowing about the initial conditions $r_=, \dot{\phi}_0$ ?

Comment: Not necessary. The question is trying to set up a good reason for the effective potential $V_{\text{eff}}$ is not just $V$, and those of us who have learnt it will recognise what the question is wanting. It is there that you will need those. For the purposes of the Lagrangian, you will not yet use it.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent and i only know the formula and where it comes from, but i haven't learnt at all about the physical meaning behind it so i sincerelly can't tell the different between $ V, V_{eff}$ from the  question's informations

Comment: I think your problem is that you are lacking a comprehensive understanding. You should be learning things properly.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent and i would learn them if i had somewhere to do it, i already studied the whole part about this in the books i have but nowhere i can find any of this informations